# Display Rank Math Meta description at the beginning of single post

Tags: excerpt

With this code

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'rm_to_excerpt' );

function rm_to_excerpt()
{   
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'   => 'post'
    ,   'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        if( '' == $post->post_excerpt )
        {
            $rm = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rank_math_description' ,true);
            if( '' != $rm )
            {
                $po = array();
                $po = get_post( $post->ID, 'ARRAY_A' );
                $po['post_excerpt'] = $rm;
                wp_update_post($po);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

i was able to use rank math meta description as my post excerpt, i want to display this same meta description at the beginning of my single post, please how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

If you want to inject the Rank Math meta description into the post content using the `the_content` filter, you can do so by adding a filter to your theme's `functions.php` file. Here's how you can achieve that:

```php
function inject_rank_math_description($content) {
    if (is_single() && !is_admin()) {
        // Check if Rank Math meta description exists
        $rank_math_description = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rank_math_description', true);

        if (!empty($rank_math_description)) {
            // Output Rank Math meta description before the post content
            $rank_math_description = '<div class="rank-math-description">' . esc_html($rank_math_description) . '</div>';
            $content = $rank_math_description . $content;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'inject_rank_math_description');
```

*Note: This is very similar to the answer by Pat J, except I've added some things.*

This code checks if you are viewing a single post (not in the admin area) and if a Rank Math meta description exists. If both conditions are met, it adds the Rank Math meta description to the beginning of the post content using the `the_content` filter.

Make sure to add this code to your theme's functions.php file.

### Option 2

You can achieve displaying the Rank Math meta description at the beginning of a single post (and definitely before your featured image) by modifying your theme's single post template. You can use the `rank_math_description` meta value you have already fetched and display it before the featured image. Here's how you can do it:

```php
<?php
// Check if Rank Math meta description exists
$rank_math_description = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rank_math_description', true);

if (!empty($rank_math_description)) {
    // Output Rank Math meta description
    echo '<div class="rank-math-description">' . esc_html($rank_math_description) . '</div>';
}

// The rest of your single post template code follows here
// This includes the featured image, post title, content, etc.
?>
```

Make sure to replace the comment `// The rest of your single post template code follows here` with your existing code for displaying the single post content, featured image, and other elements as needed. This code checks if the Rank Math meta description exists for the current post and displays it before the featured image if it's available.

Remember to place this modified code in your theme's single post template file where you want the Rank Math meta description to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter to add the metadata to the start of the post:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_421555_prepend_to_post' );
function wpse_421555_prepend_to_post( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        global $post;
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rank_math_description', true );
        if ( ! empty( $meta ) ) {
            $content = $meta . $content;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

### References

- [`the_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)
- [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/)

Comment: Thanks, this works like magic, please can you help me advance it so that it will appear before the feature image ?

Comment: Or if possible, if i can get a code to remove the feature image appearing at the beginning of the post, thanks in advance.

Comment: The featured image (probably) is added prior to the content. It'll depend on what theme you're using. You'll probably need to contact your theme's support team for assistance with that.